# Make a GIF of animated object in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, gif

I want to **export** my **animated PowerPoint object** (*not the entire slide*) as **GIF**.
Directly to GIF instead of Video if possible.

How can I do so?

Version Info:
I have PowerPoint 365 on windows 11

Comment: You better ask this type of question on [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). I recommend using [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com) to record GIFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work well if you copy/paste your animated shape(s) into a new slide that's set to the same size as your shape(s) plus any additional area needed to accommodate the shape(s) as they move (if they do).  Then do File | Export and choose GIF.

You'll probably want to make the background transparent.